# Scheduling mass delete of pdf Attachments from Account using Data Loader ClI

Tags: api, data-loader, data, bulk-delete

I was able to upload pdf attachments to account object using Data Loader CLI. I want to delete these attachments daily and upload newest pdf files.

Can somebody please suggest how can I schedule mass delete of the attachments using CLI.

Comment: Specify your delete script and create service in your OS, e.g. [win7](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/schedule-task#1TC=windows-7)

Comment: With CLI its seems difficult. Why don't you use apex(batch and scheduler)

Comment: I was able to implement it using CLI. Just needed to modify the mapping file and the process-conf file. Thank you everyone for your suggestions!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to implement it using CLI. Just needed to modify the mapping file and the process-conf file. Thank you everyone for your suggestions!